# Can Windows RT run desktop apps compiled for ARM?

Tags: windows-rt

If someone writes an ARM compiler, can desktop apps be compiled for Windows RT?

Or only apps digitally signed by Microsoft will run in desktop mode on Windows RT?

Comment: in my opinion is not off topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Only Metro/Modern/Microsoft-style UI apps can be run in Windows RT.

But, some desktop apps which are compiled and digitally-signed by Microsoft can be run in Windows RT like Office 2013 and some developer apps:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah, I know, but you can find compilers for the most exotic cpu/os combos, so I guess shortly they will be made available also for ARM/RT

Comment: They need to be digitally signed by Microsoft.

Comment: @Magnetic_dud - Even if you had a compiler, the application wouldn't run, since it must be signed by Microsoft.  They did this for security reasons, it is well known, most exploits on a Windows machine is because of third-party applications.  By starting fresh they can eliminate most if not all of the existing problems, and address on problems they can actually solve now and in the future.

Comment: Perfect, it's perfect for my mom! - The hidden question was "can winrt be infected easily hence need an av?"

Comment: I wonder if Windows Defender is installed or not

Comment: @Magnetic_dud - Malicious software exists on iOS and Android, its only a matter of time, until a Modern UI application is written. My understanding is that Windows Defender is also on Windows RT. This means anything Windows Defender can detect, can be detected on any Windows 8 and Windows RT, since all Microsoft Store applications ( specifically the ones marked to run on Windows RT and Windows 8 ) can be ran on either platform.  Microsoft learned a great deal from the mistakes of Apple and Google with their App Stores, and there were mistakes, otherwise Apple App Store wouldn't have fart apps.

Comment: @Root - Software designed to do something other then its function?  I am using the word `malicous` in a very broad sense.  http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/07/first-ios-malware-found/ has one such example.  Windows Defender is included and installed by default I believe in Windows RT and Windows 8.

Comment: iOS 6 fixes that. It asks for user permissions whenever any apps wants to access the user's data.

Answer (score 3):

Even without the Microsoft Store restrictions, the WinRT framework stack is just a subset of the full .NET Framework. So even if you managed to install something it likely wouldn't run.

Here are some of the big differences as pointed out by Krzysztof Cwalina in his 2011 BUILD talk, [*A .NET Developer's View of Windows 8 App Development*](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-930C).

[image: Metro Profile]
[image: Design requirements]
[image: Compatibility requirements]
[image: surface area]
[image: removed]
[image: removed 2]

Comment: Oh, that's why .net desktop apps won't run either

Answer (score 0):

At the moment no. Windows RT can run only run apps downloaded from Windows Store.

According to [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_RT)

> Perhaps the biggest change is that Windows RT will only run applications that have been included in Microsoft's App store.

My gut feeling is that this restriction is Artificial. Microsoft wants a share of every software that developers develop for their OS.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote please.

Comment: Point taken...I have removed the comment.

Comment: @Ramhound You really *should* always explain downvotes in a constructive manner. You don't have to explicitly mention that you downvoted, but if your own posts are downvoted as a revenge in a serial manner, the system will reverse those automatically.